C# text template: loop through enum values
I'm trying to loop through an Enum in my tt template (C# .Net project). My goal is to generate a typescript file based on this C# enum, however I'm not able to loop through my enum.
This is my C# tt file:
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" debug="false" compileroptions="/langversion=latest" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="MyNamespace.Project\bin\Debug\net8.0\MyNamespace.Project.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".ts" #>
export enum {
<#
        var keys = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
        foreach(var key in keys)
        {
            WriteLine(key.ToString());
        }
     
#>
}

I get this error:
Compiling transformation: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
I tried but all the solutions I found seems a bit weird to me - the code is nothing special, it should be a simple solution but I really can't find it. I'm using VS 2022 (17.11.5)
UPDATE
After spending hours (if not days) on this issue, I gave up. I'll write a simple Console Application to handle this simple code generation. Any further suggestion is welcome.

The error says that reference to System.Runtime is missing, try adding <#@ assembly name="System.Runtime" #>

The main problem you'll run into here is that text templates in VS are still stuck with .NET Framework. It's going to be painful and probably wont work if you want to reference a .NET 8 assembly.

There's a command line tool that supports .NET 6 but VS support is still a pipe dream.

I have recently given up on T4-templates in .NET8 specifically for this reason. The commandline tool mentioned above does not work with host-specific templates.

@Epidermis I tried that with no luck
